# You have a bad choice/You have a good choice

Tags: word-usage

If we are talking about someone's "choice" as general,  like what kind of clothes that person likes:

> You have a bad choice. (I don't like your choice)
>
> You have a good choice.(I like your choice)

Do these sound natural?

Answer (score 3):

No, they don't. "Have a bad/good choice" is grammatical, but does not mean what you seem to want.

"You have a good choice" would mean that you have a choice between two or more good alternatives. For instance, if you are in an excellent restaurant and there are several dishes you would like to try.

"You have a bad choice" would mean just the opposite. E.g. if you have to choose between going hungry and paying for heat.

To say what you want to say, add "made" between "have" and "a" in either sentence.

Comment: Although if talking about general clothing choice, rather than a specific outfit, one natural usage here would be "You have good taste" / "You have awful taste" [in clothes].

Comment: And @Smock can "taste" be used for other things as well, like paintings,bracelets, phones etc.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Yep - good taste in music, cars, wine etc.

Comment: And @Smock does this sound natural:  "Vintage cars are more to my taste.".   Is the use "to" natural?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Yep. People can have their own 'taste' or choice in cars, that may not be considered generally popular or 'in fashion'

Comment: So "to" sounds natural in this sentence @Smock ? ("Vintage cars are to my taste").  Is the use of "taste" this way in this sentence common?

Comment: @Smock , will it be more common to say "I like Vintage cars" or will it be equally common and natural to say: "Vintage cars are to my taste."

Comment: "I like vintage cars" is more of a statement (or response to "What cars do you like?") or conversation opener, whereas you might find usage such as "Vintage cars are **more** to my taste" when comparing or talking about lots of types of cars in the middle of a conversation.